# ¿Como recorrer un TXT linea por linea en ASP HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp

Actualmente estoy realizando un banner en el cual muestra datos desde SQL segun un cogido que esta en un txt.
El problema que tengo es que quiero que en ese mismo txt poner más de un código, para que lo vaya leyendo de forma individual además de que el codigo que me lea sea aleatorio, ya que con el actual me lee como si fuese todo un solo código.

```
<% archivo= request.serverVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") & "texto.txt"
set confile = createObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set fich = confile.OpenTextFile(archivo)
 texto_fichero = fich.readAll()
codigo = texto_fichero %>
```

ese es mi codigo para leer el txt actual, despues ese codigo se lo paso a la query que tengo más abajo.

EDIT: Quiero recorrer el TXT sin tener el INPUT FILE en la web, que sea de forma automatica, cosa de insertar codigos de productos  distintos y que en la web los vaya mostrandode forma aleatoria en distintos banner

```html
                              


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Productos Destacados</title>

<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
</head>
</html>

  
            <section>
                <input type="radio" name="slider-select-element" id="element1" checked="checked" />
                <input type="radio" name="slider-select-element" id="element2" />
                <input type="radio" name="slider-select-element" id="element3" />

                <div >
                    <div >
                        <div>
                   <table align="center" style="height:100%; width:100%"    >
         
<th style="color:white;"  >  
Productos Destacados </th>


<tr>

  <td align="center"   >
                   

       
     
<h1><%=descripcion%></h1>

  <p>COD. <%=codigo %>                                       
                   </p>
                 
       
  <br>
  <b><a>&#36;&nbsp;<%=FormatNumber(round(precio_venta_iva),0)%>&nbsp;&#8454;</a></b>
  <br>
  <br>
</td>
</tr>

  </table>

                    
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>

             
            </section>
```

Comment: Aun que tu pregunta carece de informacion por lo cual te sugiero que la edites agregando como quieres que se vea el resultado final, agrega el codigo del query , puedes usar la **/** aunque lo mas común es usar la coma  (es el que usa un .csv) o el punto y coma para que sea el separador para leerlo linea a linea.

claro con esto podrias usar el File.ReadAllLines() y el Split() del string para parsear cada valor o podrias usar el http://www.filehelpers.net/

esta es una libreria excelente para parsear archivos

Comment: Editado, lo estoy haciendo en bruto sin aplicaciones externas, como decía arriba
quiero que : Recorra el TXT linea por linea y en cada linea tenga un codigo de un prodructo, luego esos productos me lo muestre en distintos banner.